# Transfer iOS executable from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed an app using Xcode. Now, i want to give the executable to a friend to test. However, my friend is outside United States and I cannot deploy as I do on my test device.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Search Apple's documentation for "Adhoc distribution".

Comment: https://testflightapp.com/ try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on user's suggestions, I did some research and got my answer. Just want to share with anyone who has the same question...

What I should be doing is to make the app available for Beta testing. Below are the steps to do so.

1. Register all test devices.
2. Create distribution certificate.
3. Create ad hoc provisioning profile.
4. Archive and validate your app.
5. Create iOS App Store Package.
6. Install app on all test devices.
7. Get crash reports from testers.

For more details, please search for 'Beta Testing Your iOS App' in Apple Developer Center.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, there is no other way except adding the UDID of your friends device into the provisioning profile(be it development/distribution) and using it - Archive the project - validate once and share it across.